# Angular ng-repeat binding to array of objects in array

Tags: json, angularjs, data-binding

My current task is a refactor of the messaging structure between my service and my client.

### Setup

Assume the following JSON response is currently being returned from a service

```
{
 Foos: [
          { 
             id: "Foo1"
            ,description: "Flippity Floppity Floop"

          },
          {
             id: "Foo2"
            ,description: "Snoochy Boochy"
          }
      ]
}
```

In my Angular view, I have the following bind statement:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="foo in Foos">
     <span>{{foo.id}}</span>
     <span>{{foo.description}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

All of that is fine and good.
Renders an li for each foo in Foos and prints foo.id and foo.description.

### Refactor

The structure of the data has to shift.  I cannot treat each of the items in my array as an object any more. Each is now an array of objects and the properties on the old object become objects themselves (essentially, keyValuePairs)

The data now looks like this:

```
{
  Foos: [
            [
               {"id":"Foo1"},{"description":"Flippity Floppity Floop"}
            ],
            [
               {"id":"Foo2"},{"description":"Snoochy Boochy"}
            ]
        ]
}
```

I can predict the keys maintained within each of the inner arrays, but when I now attempt to bind to each "foo in Foos", I get a repeated item rendered to the screen with no data bound to it.

How should I now bind my repeated list of spans to {{foo.id}} and {{foo.description}}?

Comment: Can't you flatten it out by transforming the data?

Comment: @PSL yes, what I would do now would be hold `var foo = {}` iterate through the kvps and perform `for (var property in list_of_kvps){Object.assign(foo,kvp);` Then it would have been flattened and sensible for the client. Then I could use `Object.entries(foo);` to build up the PATCH list to send down and make it match the requirements of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I think that the shifted structure is inferior, but what will be will be.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="foo in Foos">
    <span>{{foo[0].id}}</span>
    <span>{{foo[1].description}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This of course assumes that the nested array will contain properties in the indicated order.

If this is no good and you actually want to use `foo.id`, you can either just update `Foos` yourself or use a filter with ng-repeat.

```
function (foos) {
    return foos.map(function (foo) {
        var obj = {};
        foo.forEach(function (prop) {
            for (var key in prop) {
                obj[key] = prop[key];
            }
        });
        return obj;
    });
}
```

Comment: I agree that it appears inferior, but each of the keyValuePairs is atomic. I presented Foo as if it is an entity with an identifier, but that's not really how the data shaped up.  I will likely retrieve "Foos" from the service and I want to bind to them as if they're a row in a table, but think of the data as if it's in 6NF. Each column is its own table...and I will need to be able to send down A list of keys with their values down to a PATCH method with nothing other than the property name to identify it across the server wall...it's odd, but it is what it is

Comment: I originally wanted to design this according to the top structure (which is how I mocked out the data when I was fleshing out the Angular controller) but it will not work for our requirements...so I exploded the entities into collections of atomic kvps.